# Is a globally convergent sequence of $\ell^2$ convergent in $\ell^\infty$ with respect to the $\ell^\infty$-Norm?

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

Let $x_n$ be a global convergent (by that we mean componentwise convergence with respect to $|\cdot|$) sequence of $\ell^2$ with the limit $x \in \ell^2$. Since $\ell^2\subset \ell^\infty$ and $x_n-x$ is a componentwise null sequence we should get $$\|x_n-x\|_{\ell^\infty}=\sup_{i \in \mathbb N}|x_n^i-x^i|=0, n→ \infty.$$ Thus we get from a globally convergent sequence in $\ell^2$ a globally convergent seqeuce with respect to the $\ell^\infty$-Norm in $\ell^\infty$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the condition $x_n\to x$ componentwise then you aren't right. Let $x_n=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ (the number $1$ is on $n$-th place). Then $x_n\to 0$ componentwise but $x_n\not\to 0$ in $L_\infty$ since $\|x_n-0\|=1$.

On the other hand, if you consider the condition $x_n\to x$ in $\ell^2$ then you're right, since $\|\cdot\|_\infty\leq \|\cdot\|_2$.